# What is the most pythonic way of printing only certain lines of a string?

Tags: python, string, line

Suppose I have a string (not a file) that spans many lines:

```
multiline_string = '''I met a traveller from an antique land
Who said: Two vast and trunkless legs of stone
Stand in the desert... near them, on the sand,
Half sunk, a shattered visage lies, whose frown,
And wrinkled lip, and sneer of cold command,
Tell that its sculptor well those passions read
Which yet survive, stamped on these lifeless things,
The hand that mocked them and the heart that fed;

And on the pedestal these words appear:
'My name is Ozymandias, king of kings;
Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!'
Nothing beside remains. Round the decay
Of that colossal wreck, boundless and bare
The lone and level sands stretch far away.'''
```

I want to get only certain lines of the string, as a single string (not as a list of strings). One way of doing it is this:

```
pedestal_lines = "\n".join(multiline_string.splitlines()[9:12])
print(pedestal_lines)
```

Output:

```
And on the pedestal these words appear:
'My name is Ozymandias, king of kings;
Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!'
```

But that way is not very good: it has to split the string into a list of strings, index this list, then join the lists back together with the `str.join()` method. Not to mention, it's ugly-looking and not very readable. Is there a more elegant/pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't see how your current method could be improved. Maybe with `itertools.islice` ?

Comment: regex? (ouch): `re.sub("^(.*\n){8}((?:.*\n){3})(.*\n){1,}",r"\2",multiline_string)`

Comment: To reference the lines by line numbers, you need to address them as lines; this requires something analogous to the `splitlines` method and the indices.  Then, your desired output format involves separate lines, so you'll have something on *that* front as well.  You could search for the line feeds in the original string to reduce the total operations, perhaps, but that looks nastier than your existing code.

Comment: it's perfectly fine as it is.

Comment: Since you are using line number information to print what you want, it makes sense to split along line breaks. I don't think it can get simpler than this. Any other method and you are working at character level.

Comment: I'd make a function out of it if you were to use it more than once. Params should be start and end (and could default to 0, -1) if start or end is not specified.

Comment: You have irregular line lengths, and whatever you use has to find those newlines somehow. `.splitlines` does that at C speed, and so does a regex. I think you'll agree that the `.splitlines` approach is a lot more readable than the regex of Jean-François's regex, that even he admits is ugly. :) `.islice` doesn't really buy you anything, since it still has to skip over the unwanted initial lines.

Comment: @PM2Ring one could think that `islice` buys memory, though, if the snippet to extract is big. But `"\n".join` has to build a list anyway, so `islice` is just ... slower in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *don't* want to split the string, you can do the following:

- use regexes to capture 3 lines after 8 lines
- count the positions of the linefeeds and slice the string just once with the proper positions

You'll forgive the one-off errors that I may have done in the code below.

**Regex**:

```
import re

print(re.sub("^(.*\n){8}((?:.*\n){3})(.*\n){1,}",r"\2",multiline_string))
```

(create a group of 8 lines, then a group of 3 lines, then the rest, replace by the second group)

**Position extract + slicing**:

```
linefeed_pos = [i for i,c in enumerate(multiline_string) if c=="\n"]
print(multiline_string[linefeed_pos[7]:linefeed_pos[11]])
```

(extract the position of the linefeed chars with list comprehension on the original string, then slice using those line-indexed positions). The drawback of this approach is that it computes *all* the indexes, not only until the upper line bound. That can be easily fixed by wrapping a generator comprehension in a list comprehension to stop just when the indices are no longer needed:

```
linefeed_pos = [next (i for i,c in enumerate(multiline_string) if c=="\n") for _ in range(12)]
```

Maybe one slicing/extract is better than splitting & joining for performance (I understand that seeing a big list going to waste just to pick 3 lines is unbearable), but I wouldn't call that pythonic.

Both methods explained above should be faster than yours if you have a lot of lines if performance/memory matters. If it doesn't, then stick to your solution.

Comment: Smart, but remember ...  the question was `Is there a more elegant/pythonic way of achieving this?`. I'd say the answer is a simple `No`.

Comment: I perfectly agree with this.

Comment: FWIW, that `linefeed_pos` list comp is around 10 to 30 times slower than `.splitlines`, depending on the size of the input string, and the proportion of linefeeds it contains.

Comment: I think we can shortcut it if the lines are at the start of the text, I'll edit